# Single theme folder for mod_autoindex with virtualhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-autoindex

I succesfully installed (in localhost and virtualhost, running on OSX) [Apaxy](https://github.com/AdamWhitcroft/Apaxy) to have a better view of my web directories. Each `.htaccess` works fine if `theme` folder is in their same directory, but what if I want to keep only one `theme` folder, for example in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`?
I tried to edit the vhost `.htaccess` from this working format:

```
AddIcon theme/icons/blank.png ^^BLANKICON^^
AddIcon theme/icons/folder.png ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon theme/icons/folder-home.png ..
HeaderName theme/header.html
ReadmeName theme/footer.html
IndexStyleSheet theme/style.css
```

to this (not working):

```
AddIcon /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/icons/blank.png ^^BLANKICON^^
AddIcon /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/icons/folder.png ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/icons/folder-home.png ..
HeaderName /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/header.html
ReadmeName /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/footer.html
IndexStyleSheet /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/style.css
```

But I don't understand why, since it is just a path and I'm sure those files exist.

Does it only works if `.htaccess` and `theme` folder are in the same directory?

Is it possible to set all those mod_autoindex's directives in apache config file? In order to have it working for any directory missing the index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddIcon /Library/WebServer/Documents/theme/icons/blank.png ^^BLANKICON^^
```

AddIcon expects a URL – whereas what you have here rather looks like a file system path.

You need to specify the URL from the root of your domain – so if your icon is available via `http://example.com/theme/icons/blank.png`, you would need to use

```
AddIcon /theme/icons/blank.png ^^BLANKICON^^
```

> Is it possible to set all those mod_autoindex's directives in apache config file?

The Apache documentation tells you for every directive, in which context it can be used.

Go look up for example the [AddIcon](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon) directive, and you see that it says there:

```
Context: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just noticed in the console how to correct the path for those files. Thank you about the AddIcon input too